# F# Or-Tools Sat Solver

Tags: f#, or-tools

I am experimenting with F# and want to do some constraint programming where I use Or-Tools. I have previously used the package together with Python, but I can’t get it to work with F#.

I follow the C# example: https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver#c_5

But get an error when try to add a constraint:
[image]

Comment: The API overrides the `!=` operator to return a `BoundedLinearExpression`: http://google.github.io/or-tools/dotnet/classGoogle_1_1OrTools_1_1Sat_1_1LinearExpr.html#ad84654155044b33c43239a95578da09d. So maybe you could provide your own operator or function that does the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this is kind of annoying, but it's how consuming operators that were overloaded in C# from F# works.

The reason why you couldn't use `!=` like this is because:

1. The operator `!=` is (and this is unusual) overloaded in C# as a static operator on the `LinearExpr` class.
2. The operator `!=` compiles down to `op_Inequality`, but `op_Inequality` in F# is `<>`, not `!=`
3. F# already defines `<>` as a generic operator that accepts any member that satisfies the `equality` constraint, which `LinearExpr` does
4. The defined operator `<>` resolves correctly, and produces a `bool`, which is incompatible with `model.Add` because it doesn't expect a `bool`

The solution is to explicitly qualify your access to the operator like so:

```
LinearExpr.(<>) (x, y)
```

Note that because it takes tupled arguments in its definition, you must also tuple your arguments and you can't use it like a "normal" operator.

Here is the full F# solution, with a few small tweaks to make it idiomatic:

```
#r "nuget: Google.OrTools"

open Google.OrTools.Sat

let model = CpModel()

// Creates the variables.
let num_vals = 3L;

let x = model.NewIntVar(0L, num_vals - 1L, "x")
let y = model.NewIntVar(0L, num_vals - 1L, "y")
let z = model.NewIntVar(0L, num_vals - 1L, "z")

// Creates the constraints.
model.Add(LinearExpr.(<>) (x, y))

// Creates a solver and solves the model.
let solver = CpSolver();
let status = solver.Solve(model)

if status = CpSolverStatus.Optimal then
    printfn $"x = {solver.Value(x)}"
    printfn $"y = {solver.Value(y)}"
    printfn $"z = {solver.Value(z)}"
```

A way to make this a bit nicer from  F# is to define a module of operators that map to the `LinearExpr` operators like so:

```
module LinearExprOperators =
    let ( ^<> ) (x: LinearExpr) (y: LinearExpr) = LinearExpr.(<>) (x, y)
    let ( ^= ) (x: LinearExpr) (y: LinearExpr) = LinearExpr.(=) (x, y)
```

Then you can use those operators instead. Another annoyance is that it appears that `+` and `-` and `*` work just fine, because the F# type doesn't produce a different type like `bool`.

So in short, this particular API is a little annoying to use from F#.